# Setting symbol rendering based on feature visible length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, rendering, length

I am displaying symbols at the middle of lines and I would like them to be visible only when the length of the feature displayed on my screen is long enough (which I call "visible length" in the title of this message).

I found a workaround using a condition based on map scale:

[image]

```
if(@map_scale>5000, $length>50, $length>30)
```

Is there a way to do it at any scale? For example a condition saying "don't show the symbol if the feature length on screen is less than X cm"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply calculate the length on the map canvas using `$length / @map_scale` and than check if this is longer than the threshold you want: `$length / @map_scale > X` (don't forget to convert units from project CRS to cm).